# BigQuery timestamp current date minus x days

Tags: datetime, google-bigquery, timestamp

I have a TIMESTAMP column with dates that I need to filter. I need to grab the data that is 5 days old. So `current date - 5 days`. My data is in BigQuery. I tried the following query:

```
where created_time >= (TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), DAY), INTERVAL -5 DAY)
```

I got an error: `Unexpected INTERVAL expression`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `TIMESTAMP_ADD()`:

```
where created_time > TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), DAY), INTERVAL -5 DAY)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you, I have accepted the answer.